# Lumen Cache\Store is not instantiable

Tags: caching, laravel-5, lumen

I'm quite new to Laravel and Lumen, so my question may be a little simple, but I couldn't find any useful answer yet.

Lumen version is `5.1`.

So I tried to create a data repository supported by a cache. Firstly I want to use FileStore, then I want to move to some more appropriate.

I tried to inject Cache repository like this:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Repositories;

    use Illuminate\Cache\Repository;

    class DataRepository
    {
        private $cache;

        public function __construct(Repository $cache)
        {
            $this->cache = $cache;
        }
    }
```

It seemed pretty simple to me. But when I try to use this repo in my controller, and tried to inject this repo into it, during instantiation I get the following error:

```
BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 749:
Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Store] is not instantiable.
```

I guessed the repository cannot find the matching and useable store implementation. When I tried to bind the Store to \Illumante\Cache\FileStore like this:

```
$this->app->bind(\Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Store::class, \Illuminate\Cache\FileStore::class);
```

I got a new kind of error:

```
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #1 [ <required> $directory ]] in class Illuminate\Cache\FileStore
```

I guess I have a more complicated config issue, so I didn't want to walk through the dependency tree.

In my `.env` I have these:

`CACHE_DRIVER=file` and `SESSION_DRIVER=file`

In Lumen I explicitly enabled the facades, the DotEnv (and the eloquent also for my data repositories).

```
Dotenv::load(__DIR__.'/../');

$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);

$app->withFacades();
$app->withEloquent();
```

I tried to add a cache.php configuration. In the bootstrap/app.php I added `$app->configure('cache');` to use it with the following configs:

```
<?php

return [
    'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),

    'stores' => [
        'file' => [
            'driver' => 'file',
            'path' => storage_path('framework/cache'),
        ],
    ],
];
```

Could you help me, how can I bootstrap the Cache properly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Answer

The cache implementation in Lumen is registered as:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository
```

**Not**

```
Illuminate\Cache\Repository
```

So you may change your code to:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository;

class DataRepository
{
    private $cache;

    public function __construct(Repository $cache)
    {
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }
}
```

> **P.S** You don't need to configure cache, since Lumen will configure any cache configuration automatically.

### Tricks

But if you still want to use `Illuminate\Cache\Repository`, you may bind it first in your `ServiceProvider` or `bootstrap/app.php` file:

```
use Illuminate\Cache\Repository as CacheImplementation;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository as CacheContract;

$app->singleton(CacheImplementation::class, CacheContract::class);
```

Comment: Thank you, that was totally it :)